# core 3.1 error.Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

> .Net core 3.1

```
    `DBContext dbEntity;
    public CompanyService(DBContext _dbEntity)
    {
        dbEntity = _dbEntity;
    }
   `public async Task<string> Save(ModelCompany comp)
    {
                await dbEntity.Company.AddAsync(comp);
                await dbEntity.SaveChangesAsync(); 
                return "Saved";
    }
```

while insert data got error on `await dbEntity.SaveChangesAsync();` section

***Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'DBContext'.***

how can solve this.Also need to add one more table data on transaction commit and rollback base.how can do it on .net core 3.1

Comment: How did you configure your DbContext?Could you share with us?

Comment: public class DBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<ModelCompany> company { get; set; }
  }

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your context life time in startup is Singleton not scope. (i.e. services.AddSingleton)